# What is the MYOB API's queries per second limit?

Tags: myob

I'm getting a `Developer Over Qps` response while working with the [account live api](http://developer.myob.com/api/accountright/v2/).

I'm going to use a limiter to throttle my requests, and would like to know what the allowed qps is.

Any ideas?

(I'll get a rough idea through trial and error, but it'd be sweet to know the exact figure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

George here from the MYOB API Team. That's a pretty close estimation you managed to reach there, the actual limit is 5 calls per second which is usually quite enough for most people. It is flexible however, if you reach a stage that you need more than that.

Cheers!

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much George!  Yeah, the import is only taking a few seconds, so 5 qps should be all good.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I've found that a request every 175ms (5.7 qps) works whereas every 170ms (5.8 qps) breaks.

If anyone from the MYOB team could confirm this number that'd be great.